# Why do I get "InvalidCastException"

Tags: c#, .net

I have my code as below

```
((LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "INSERT";
```

I got the error as

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly?  Your question is missing a lot of detail.

Comment: Well, a `TextBox` is not a `LinkButton` - so you cannot cast `TextBox` to `LinkButton`. Just as the error said...

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm... The issue seems to be that GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0] is an object of class `TextBox` rather than `LinkButton`. You should fix your gridview contents.

Comment: Hi Alexander how could I fix my gridview contents? what should I do?

Comment: I'm afraid this is out of scope of a SO question, especially without any code. In general, make sure you have placed in the first cell of the first row a `LinkButton` (if it really should be a `LinkButton`).

Comment: Actually my task is to create a gridview control and perform insert, edit, update, delete actions..If anyone can help me in this, it would be of great help

Comment: @user1185691 - If you have specific questions we are willing to help.  If you expect us to simply provide you the answer you are barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 1):

Cast to `Control` instead of `LinkButton` if all you need is `Text` property:

```
((Control)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = "INSERT";
```

By the way, doing this way isn't quite right. You should check possible null's and index overflow issues.